# react component iterating over data and mapping a complicated row structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Data looks like this:

```
const items = [
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=1", title: "BMW 545", price: "6.500$" },
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=2", title: "Mercedes GL", price: "16.500$" },
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=3", title: "Toyota", price: "16.500$" },
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=4", title: "Porsche", price: "16.500$" },
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=5", title: "VW Golf", price: "16.500$" },
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=6", title: "Infinity GS", price: "16.500$" },
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=7", title: "Ford GT", price: "16.500$" },
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=8", title: "Mitsubishi Lancer", price: "16.500$" },
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=9", title: "Fiat Punto", price: "16.500$" },
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=10", title: "Pegaout Corsa", price: "16.500$" },
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=11", title: "Open Corsa", price: "16.500$" },
  { image: "http://loremflickr.com/320/320/sport-car?random=12", title: "VW Passat", price: "16.500$" }
]
```

final structure should look like this:

```
  <div className="Grid">
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size1of2"><Card type="double"/></div>
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size1of2"><Card type="double"/></div>
  </div>
  <div className="Grid">
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size1of4"><Card/></div>
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size2of4"><Card type="double"/></div>
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size1of4"><Card/></div>
  </div>
  <div className="Grid">
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size1of2"><Card type="double"/></div>
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size1of2"><Card type="double"/></div>
  </div>
  <div className="Grid">
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size1of4"><Card/></div>
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size2of4"><Card type="double"/></div>
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size1of4"><Card/></div>
  </div>
  <div className="Grid">
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size1of2"><Card type="double"/></div>
    <div className="Grid-cell u-size1of2"><Card type="double"/></div>
  </div>
```

image / title / price can be passed to Card component.

I started by creating a `for` loop, but that thing very soon started to look like a monstrosity of `if/else`.

Is it possible to use `map` for this? or there a better library for handling this kind of templating?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide a little more explanation around how your data structure relates to the markup that you want to output? What makes some of the Grids have two divs in them and some have three and why do some of the Card components have a double type and some don't?

Comment: @ZacBraddy its purely visual, I added design to clear it up.

Comment: Please add an example of code you have written. Asking for this much code to be written without providing an example of what you have tried goes beyond the scope of StackOverflow questions.

Comment: @RossAllen I was asking for general pointers, not exact code. In fact Zac's answer already helped me implement it. Piotr just went ahead and implemented it all - for which I'm grateful, but was not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should deliver the desired DOM grid: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/rrdBjX

You would now need to clean the code and apply proper styling.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {   
    const GridArrays = {};

    items.forEach((item, index, array) => {
      if (index % 5 === 0) {
        GridArrays[Object.keys(GridArrays).length] = array.slice(index, index + 2);
      } else if (index % 5 === 2) {
        GridArrays[Object.keys(GridArrays).length] = array.slice(index, index + 3);
      }
    });

    const renderGrids = Object.keys(GridArrays).map(key => {
      if (Number(key) % 2 === 0) {
        return <TwoCars cars={GridArrays[key]} />;
      } else {
        return <ThreeCars cars={GridArrays[key]} />;
      }
    });

    return (
      <div>
        {renderGrids}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class TwoCars extends React.Component {
  render() {   
    const renderTwoCars = this.props.cars.map((car, index) => {
      return (
        <div className="grid-cell u-size1of2">
          <Card type="double" image={car.image} title={car.title} price={car.price} />
        </div>
      );
    });  

    return (
      <div className="grid-wrapper">
        {renderTwoCars}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class ThreeCars extends React.Component {
  render() {   
    const renderThreeCars = this.props.cars.map((car, index) => {
      return (
        <div className={index % 2 === 0 ? "grid-cell u-size1of4" : "grid-cell u-size2of4"}>
          <Card image={car.image} title={car.title} price={car.price} type={index % 2 !== 0 ? 'double' : ''} />
        </div>
      );
    });  

    return (
      <div className="grid-wrapper">
        {renderThreeCars}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Card extends React.Component {
  render() { 
    let style = this.props.type === 'double' ? 'double' : 'single';

    return (
      <div className={`card-${style}`}>
        <div className={`image-${style}`}>
          <img className={`img-${style}`} src={this.props.image} />
        </div>
        <div className={`desc-${style}`}>
          <h4>{this.props.title}</h4>
          <p>{this.props.price}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Salivan, I have updated the codepen, the code is pure react and css. Would you like me to add anything or does it answer your question.

Comment: hey! thank you so much for your trouble... you didn't have to write it completely though, I was just looking for general pointers not specific implementation. Your code looks, awesome, while I won't copy it, I'm taking the concept :)

Comment: Once I started fiddling with it I could not stop :) Such a great challenge.

Comment: I know, and I won't give up that pleasure this easy. I just glanced your implementation I will try to do all details myself :))

Comment: only if I'm stuck I will get back to your code. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If it were me making this application what I'd do is make three more components. A TwoCardRow component and a ThreeCardRow component and then I'd make a container component whose job it is to chop up the array you've got there into groups of two and three respectively in a loop and just pass the appropriate number of array items to those Two and Three card row components.